# What processor architecture to use for debian installation

Tags: debian, cpu

Processor Type: Intel(R) Xeon (R) CPU E3-1225

Question: What is the processor architecture for the above processor?

Available options: amd64,arm64,armel,armhf,i386,mips,mips64el,mipsel,ppc64el,s390x

I want to install debian on it.

Comment: Most PC are amd64 which yours is.  You can install this program in live installer and see details: `inxi -SG` What video card as you may need boot parameter like nomodeset. You can replace quiet splash with nomodeset, see detail screen shot: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters & https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Be sure to choose UEFI boot since newer system.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 64-bit Intel processor (Specifications [Intel® Xeon® Processor E3-1225](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52270/intel-xeon-processor-e3-1225-6m-cache-3-10-ghz.html)).
This means you want to pick the **amd64** option ([quick history reference on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#History_2)).